# Called the same Activity into more than one class -Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to call the same Activity into more than one class, **but** when I attempt to use the same Activity in two different classes I get error that my Application stopped!

The **First call** for My Activity was **done** without any error:

```
            Intent prevIntent=new Intent(ChequesInfo.this,GetItemsActivity.class);
            prevIntent.putExtra("ip", string);
            prevIntent.putExtra("dbname", dbname);
            prevIntent.putExtra("dbpass", dbpass);
            startActivity(prevIntent);
```

But in **Second call** on another class it gives me error:

```
            Intent prevIntent=new Intent(InventoryStock.this,GetItemsActivity.class);
            prevIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            prevIntent.putExtra("ip", ip);
            prevIntent.putExtra("dbname", dbname);
            prevIntent.putExtra("dbpass", dbpass);
            startActivity(prevIntent);
```

**GetItemsActivity** Class used to get items from the server, which:

```
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(GetItemsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Items. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {     
                try {
                    result=bringData("http://"+ip+"/StatementOfAccount/getItems.php",dbname,dbpass);

                } catch (Exception e) {    
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Intent prevIntent=new Intent(GetItemsActivity.this,intentname);
                    prevIntent.putExtra("ip", ip);
                    prevIntent.putExtra("dbname", dbname);
                    prevIntent.putExtra("dbpass", dbpass);
                    dbI.close();
                    startActivity(prevIntent);

                }
            dilimeter = result.toString().split("!");

            //to save all items in table 
            try {
                dbI.open();
                dbI.insertItem( dilimeter,dilimeter.length); 
                dbI.close();

            }  catch(Exception ex){
                Intent prevIntent=new Intent(GetItemsActivity.this,Classname);
                prevIntent.putExtra("ip", ip);
                prevIntent.putExtra("dbname", dbname);
                prevIntent.putExtra("dbpass", dbpass);
                dbI.close();
                startActivity(prevIntent);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
               if(pDialog != null){
                   pDialog.dismiss();

                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your work Done! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent prevIntent=new Intent(GetItemsActivity.this,intentname);
                prevIntent.putExtra("ip", ip);
                prevIntent.putExtra("dbname", dbname);
                prevIntent.putExtra("dbpass", dbpass);
                startActivity(prevIntent);

        }
    }
```

**bringData** method to get data from server:

```
public String  bringData(String url,String jsonValue, String jsonValue1) throws JSONException { 
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        json.put("dbname",jsonValue);
        json.put("dbpass", jsonValue1);

         JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
         postjson.put(json);

         // Post the data:
         httppost.setHeader("json",json.toString());
         httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);

         // Execute HTTP Post Request
         System.out.print(json);
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

         // for JSON:
         if(response != null) {
                InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                // String item=null;
                try {
                     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                          f=line;

                       }

                     } catch (IOException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     } finally {
                         try {
                             is.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                             e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                   }

              }

             } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             }
          return f;
        }
```

The **LogCat Error**:

```
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error   occured while executing doInBackground()
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at SOA.com.GetItemsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(GetItemsActivity.java:439)
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at SOA.com.GetItemsActivity$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(GetItemsActivity.java:1)
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-14 03:41:43.306: E/AndroidRuntime(2430):     ... 3 more
01-14 03:41:49.166: I/Choreographer(2430): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-14 03:41:49.416: I/Choreographer(2430): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-14 03:41:50.556: I/Choreographer(2430): Skipped 292 frames!  The application may be   doing too much work on its main thread.
01-14 03:41:51.316: I/Choreographer(2430): Skipped 129 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

**Although** I attempt some proposed solutions (but with no chance to run with me!) which are:

Setting either the following flags for intent:

- Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
- Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

**Override** onDestroy() and onPause() methods.

Is there any problem when called the same Activity in more than one class?

Any help will be appreciated,
...

Comment: where GetItemsActivity.java:439 is it?

Comment: exactly it's a null point exception.may be there's a string is null.

Comment: This line please:  dilimeter = result.toString().split("!");

Comment: ok,i think result is null.please check it.System.out.println(result);

Comment: But it works for me when called it for the first time and do not gives me null point exception! but, when call the same activity in different class it does not work! I don't know why?!

Comment: hard to tell without knowing what `bringData` do

Comment: where are u using this asynctask? show code.

Comment: (but I would be tempted to think it is related to dbname and dbpass being empty or something)

Comment: I think there are no problem in code! since it works when called it in the first time! but when attempt to use it for the second time it does not work! ...

Comment: always can no work in the second time?

Comment: OMG! Just waste more than two hours for killer mistake! you are right @njzk2  the error that the ip value was empty ! really I am thing to have error like that! :( :( :(  thanks all !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you All to give me suggestions for my problem. Finally I got a solution.

**Reason for the Error:** The ip address value being empty! I solved this issue, then everything goes well! sure after waste more than two hours on this killer mistake :( !!